# How can I create a "non-autodispose" provider with riverpod_annotation?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, riverpod-generator, riverpod-annotation

#### Observations

if I create a provider using [riverpod_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod_annotation) as follow

```dart
import 'package:riverpod_annotation/riverpod_annotation.dart';

part 'foo.g.dart';

@riverpod
String foo(FooRef ref) => 'foo';
```

said provider will needlessly be a `AutoDisposeProvider<String>`
rather than just a `Provider`

```dart
final fooProvider = Provider((ref) => 'foo');
```

#### Question

How can I generate a regular provider with `riverpod_annotation`?

#### Additional informations

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.3.0
  riverpod_annotation: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  riverpod_generator: ^2.0.0
```

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.6, on macOS 13.2.1 22D68 darwin-arm64, locale en-EE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this:

```dart
@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
String foo(FooRef ref) => 'foo';
```